# How can I use a xaml user control as a specific type

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a ribbon control, and in the control I want to add a tab item as a user control so it can be added to multiple tabs. I also want the tab item to be designed in xaml.

I want to add the user control as a tab item:

```
 <igRibbon:XamRibbon Name="_xamRibbon" Theme="Scenic">
      <igRibbon:XamRibbon.Tabs>
            <view1:DataManagmentTab/> <!--User control tab-->
      </igRibbon:XamRibbon.Tabs>
 </igRibbon:XamRibbon>
```

User control is the tab item it is expecting:

```
<igRibbon:RibbonTabItem
    xmlns:igRibbon="clr-namespace:Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon;assembly=InfragisticsWPF4.Ribbon.v14.1"
    xmlns:infragistics="clr-namespace:Components.Tool.Infragistics;assembly=Components.Tool.Infragistics"
    Header="Test Tab" Visibility="Visible">
<igRibbon:RibbonGroup Caption="Test Group" Name="DM1">

</igRibbon:RibbonGroup>
```

The code behind for the user control:

```
    public partial class DataManagmentTab : RibbonTabItem
{
    public DataManagmentTab()
    {

    }
}
```

Ribbon tab item is what the user control is expected to be, but it never shows up in the ribbon. Any ideas? It is like the xaml for the user control is never being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

`RibbonTabItem` is *not* a user control, as such you need to [template it like any other custom control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278064%28VS.96%29.aspx#defining_the_visual_structure_and_visual_behavior_of_a_control_in_a_controltemplate). E.g. define a `Style` with the proper `TargetType` in `Application.Resources` that sets the `Template`.